# Eigenvectors with dgeev in Maxima

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, eigenvector, maxima

I am finding eigenvectors with the function dgeev in maxima and comparing them with eigenvectors I find from the same matrix but using mathematica.

In the odd column right eigenvectors in maxima are the same as in mathematica but not the even. And the even column left eigenvectors are the same in mathematica but not the odd. if I were to take odd column right eigenvectors and even column eigenvectors I would have what mathematica prints out.

I do not fully understand what is going on here, does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Would you share some actual results? Also sharing on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com may help you get the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors aren't unique, so the actual result depends on conventions for normalization and ordering. A better way to check the result is to verify that the difference between the original matrix and the product of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues is zero.